# Calculate probability of choosing a winning block out of 5 blocks, extend to 9 scenarios

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a game board with 9 rows. Each row has 5 blocks. One of out those five blocks will be a bomb. You have to choose a block in each row. In order to advance, you have to choose the block without the bomb.

What's the probability of advancing through row 1?
What's the probability of advancing all the way down to row 9 and picking the correct block there?

1 xxxxx

2 xxxxx

3 xxxxx

4 xxxxx

5 xxxxx

6 xxxxx

7 xxxxx

8 xxxxx

9 xxxxx

Answer (score 3):

This is just a question of independent probability.
If one in five blocks is a bomb (1/5), then 4/5 blocks are safe (do not have a bomb).

So the probability of advancing through row 1 is 4/5.

To get all the way to row 9, we use independent probability (assuming the block the bomb occupies is a random one each time). So we multiply 4/5 by 4/5 as many times as there are rows we want to get through:
$$ {4/5}^9 = 0.134$$
So the probability of getting all the way to row 9 and picking the correct block there is 0.134.